# SQLAlchemy use ID in other column when inserting (possibly even with sqlsoup)

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sqlsoup

Given a model `tasks` with columns `id: int (primary_key), file_path: string`, using SQLAlchemy, I want to do the following in one transaction:

```
task = Task()
db.add(task)
db.commit()
task.file_path = "/path/to/%d.txt" % task.id
db.commit()
```

Note that I need to commit() first before I can access `task.id`, hence the two commits.

Is this possible, either by using some kind of lambda, or by writing a setter function/insert callback in the `Task` model?

I am using PostgreSQL for the backend and know how I could do that using triggers in the DB. I am looking for a more pythonic way than a pl/pgsql solution.

If you happen to know the answer using SQLSoup, I would also be extremely thankful. For the sake of completeness, the SQLSoup equivalent for the first two lines would be `task = db.tasks.insert()`, the other 3 lines remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not a good idea to save a value for `file_path`. I'd recommend to consider to do something like:

```
class Task(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, primary_key=True)
    @property
    def file_path(self):
        #return "/path/to/%d.txt" % self.id
        return "/path/to/{0:06d}.txt".format(self.id)
```

This way `task.file_path` doesn't need to be saved seperately and is more flexible (for the case you change the directory where you keep your files).

Amendment: For the case there are really different paths required the following could solve that:

```
class Task(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'task'
  id = sqAl.Column(sqAl.Integer, primary_key=True)
  _file_path = sqAl.Column(sqAl.String)
  @property
  def file_path(self):
    return self._file_path.format(self.id)
  @file_path.setter
  def file_path(self, fp):
    self._file_path = fp
```

And then give the format string as argument:

```
task = Task(file_path="/path/to/{0:06d}.txt")
```

Comment: I appreciate your advice, and in most cases I would've solved it exactly like that. In my use case, the database is used by two separate instances, which behave in a producer-consumer way. In addition, there are multiple different producers that feed tasks to the same consumer, and which may want different file/folder structures. Long story short, I am very certain that in my architecture, the use case above makes sense, and I'd appreciate a solution for it.